# How to handle a Promise from an encapsulated function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, google-cloud-firestore

This is a concept I've been struggling to understand: I have a service in which I'm encapsulating my Firestore DB calls. In this class I have a method to add a doc to a collection:

```
createOrder(order: Order) {
    let o = {user: order.user, total: order.total, items: this.parseItems(order.items), uid: order.uid};
    this.ordersRef.add(o).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

As you can see, I'm able to handle the promise within the service class itself. My question is: how can I handle that result when I call the function from another class? Look:

```
placeOrder() {
  let order = new Order(this.userProvider.getUser(), this.cart.getItems());
  this.orderService.createOrder(order);
}
```

What I want to do is something like

> this.orderService.createOrder(order).then(res => {}).catch(err => {});

How can I achieve that?

Comment: why can't you simply `return this.ordersRef.add.... `?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think all you need to do is return `res` and the call to `this.orderService...`. Edit: or perhaps just the latter.

Comment: @MeirionHughes it worked just as you and Mark below said, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember that `then()` also returns a promise. So you can return the whole chain and still have a promise to call `then()` on:

```
createOrder(order: Order) {
    let o = {user: order.user, total: order.total, items:       
    this.parseItems(order.items), uid: order.uid};

    // return the promise to the caller
    return this.ordersRef.add(o).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        // you only need this then() if you have further processing
        // that you don't want the caller to do
        // make sure you return something here to pass
        // as a value for the next then
        return res
    })
   /* let the caller catch errors unless you need to process before the called get it.
   .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
   */
 }
```

Now this should work fine:

```
this.orderService.createOrder(order)
.then(res => {})
.catch(err => {});
```